# JavaScript/JQuery: Stop script until modal form submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, this is probably an easy one, but I just can't wrap my head around how to do it from the examples online.

**Background:** My code displays a modal form `$("#multi_med_modal_form")` asking for user input.  The input from the modal form is used to finish populating some html `$('#med_output')` before moving on to the next line from an AJAX response.

**Problem:** After the modal displays, the code continues to execute subsequent lines from the AJAX response so that by the time the user submits the modal form, the variables have changed and the program (understandably) throws an error.

**Question:** How do I make JavaScript/JQuery wait for stop the code at `$("#multi-submit-btn").click()` below?

````
    $("#med_input_form").submit(function(event){
        console.log('Med Input Form Submitted');
        event.preventDefault();

        var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{% url "medrec_v2:post_medrec" %}',
            data: serializedData,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#med_output').html("");

                var med_ajax = JSON.parse(response["med_output"]);

                med_ajax.line.forEach(line => {
                    console.log(line)
                    input_text = line[0]
                    med_list = line[1]
                    dose = line[2]            
                    if (med_list.length == 0) {
                        // <!---Need new Modal!-->
                        
                    } else if (med_list.length > 1){
                        input_name = modal_option_builder("multi", line);
                        $("#multi_med_modal").modal('show');
//!!!----------  WAIT FOR USER TO SUBMIT MODAL FORM HERE!! ------------------!!!//
                        $("#multi-submit-btn").click( () => { 
                            radio_id = $("input[name='" + input_name + "']:checked").val()
                            for (i = 1; i < med_list.length; i++) { 
                                if (med_list[i].id == radio_id) {
                                    radio_med = med_list[i];
                                    break;
                                }
                            };
                            radio_html_name = html_builder(radio_med)
                            $('#med_output').append("<tr><th scope='row'>"+radio_html_name+"</th><td>"+dose+"</td><td>"+ radio_med.med_commonuses+ "</td></tr>");
                            $("#multi_med_modal").modal('hide');
                        })
                    } else {
                        html_name = html_builder(med_list[0]);          
                        $('#med_output').append("<tr><th scope='row'>"+html_name+"</th><td>"+dose+"</td><td>"+ med_list[0].med_commonuses+ "</td></tr>");
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    });


    /*<------------Build title and body for Modal form----------->
    send to form to select correct medicaiton*/
    function modal_option_builder(modal_type, line) {
        if (modal_type =="multi") {
            $("#multi_med_modal_form").empty()

            input_text = line[0]
            med_list = line[1]
            $("#modaltitle").html('Multiple medications found for "'+input_text+'"!'); //set modal title to line string where multiple medications found

            form_lines=[]
            for (i = 0; i < med_list.length; i++) { 
                input_type = "radio";
                input_id = input_type +"_"+med_list[i].id;
                input_name = input_type+'-'+ input_text.replace(' ', '-');
                $("#multi_med_modal_form").append(`
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="`+input_type+`" name="`+input_name+`" id="`+input_id+`" value="`+med_list[i].id+`">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="`+input_id+`">`+med_list[i].display_name+`</label>
                        </div>`);
            };
            return input_name;
        } else if (modal_type = "no_match") {
            $("#modaltitle").html('No matches found for"'+med_list[0]+'"!');
            $("#multi_med_modal_form").html("");

        }
        
    };```

Like I said, this is probably easy, I just can't figure out how to do it.  Thank you!
````

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  There's no way to "stop" the code from executing like I was describing (as far as I know).  I just had to assign an `id` to the html element I was creating to  populate with user feedback afterwards.

Here's the code:

```
    /*------------AJAX FUNCTION---------------------*/

    $("#med_input_form").submit(function(event){
        console.log('Med Input Form Submitted');
        event.preventDefault();

        var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{% url "medrec_v2:post_medrec" %}',
            data: serializedData,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#med_output').empty();
                prevMedList = []
                var med_ajax = JSON.parse(response["med_output"]);
                line_no = 0
                med_ajax.line.forEach(line => {
                    console.log(line)
                    line_no += 1
                    input_text = line[0]
                    med_list = line[1]
                    dose = line[2]
                    sig = line[3]
                    $('#med_output').append("<tr id='output_"+line_no+"'></tr>");            
                    if (med_list.length == 0) {
                        
                        $("#no-med-modal").modal("show");
                        console.log("no-med-modal shown")
                        $("#multi-submit-btn").click( () => { 

                        });

                        
                    } else if (med_list.length > 1){
                        input_name = multi_modal_builder(line);
                        $("#multi-med-modal").modal('show');
                        //----------  WAIT FOR $("#multi-submit-btn").click() HERE!! -----------//
                        $("#multi-submit-btn").click( () => { 
                            radio_id = $("input[name='" + input_name + "']:checked").val()
                            for (i = 1; i < med_list.length; i++) { 
                                if (med_list[i].id == radio_id) {
                                    radio_med = med_list[i];
                                    break;
                                }
                            };
                            radio_html_name = html_builder(radio_med)
                            $('#output_'+line_no).append("<tr><th scope='row'>"+radio_html_name+"</th><td>"+dose+"</td><td>"+ sig+ "</td><td>"+radio_med.med_commonuses+ "</td></tr>");
                            $("#multi-med-modal").modal('hide');
                            prevMedList.append([radio_id,dose]);
                        })
                    } else {
                        for (i in prevMedList) {
                            if (med_list[0].id == prevMedList[0]){
                                prev="true";
                                break;
                        }}; 
                        if (prev=="true"){continue};
                        html_name = html_builder(med_list[0]);          
                        // console.log(html_name);
                        $('#output_'+line_no+'').append("<th scope='row'>"+html_name+"</th> <td>"+dose+"</td> <td>"+ sig+ "</td> <td>"+med_list[0].med_commonuses+ "</td>");
                        prevMedList.append([radio_id,dose]);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    });
```